# Split pyspark dataframe column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have the below pyspark dataframe column.

```
Column_1
daily_trend_navigator
weekly_trend_navigator
day_of_week_trend_display
day_of_month_trend_notifier
empty_navigator
unique_notifier
```

I have to split the above column and only extract till trend if the column has trend as part of it or else I have to extract what ever is there before first occurence of "_"

Expected output:

```
column_1
daily_trend
weekly_trend
day_of_week_trend
day_of_month_trend
empty
unique
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I can split using delimiter underscore.. but not sure how to handle incase of trend. I cannot go by delimiter from last as it can have many delimiters after trend too

Comment: can you have words such as "trendy" ? or words which finish with "trend" ?

Comment: No.. it will be like trend only and not trendy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably does not take into account all the cases, but at least, it works with your example.

1. you deal with the "trend" case : split by trend if it exists
2. you split by _ otherwise

```py
df.withColumn(
    "Column_1",
    F.when(
        F.col("Column_1").contains("trend"),
        F.concat(F.split("Column_1", "trend").getItem(0), F.lit("trend")),
    ).otherwise(F.split("Column_1", "_").getItem(0)),
).show()
+------------------+                                                            
|          Column_1|
+------------------+
|       daily_trend|
|      weekly_trend|
| day_of_week_trend|
|day_of_month_trend|
|             empty|
|            unique|
+------------------+
```